# Show data in header view according to category in swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Want to achive this][image: This Iam geeting by code I did]

Server response:

```
{
    "success": {
        "allDishes": [
            {
                "_id": "5dd78586c2f2871d84061929",
                "dishType": "non_veg",
                "recommended": true,
                "isCustomizable": false,
                "isAddons": false,
                "availability": true,
                "restaurantId": "5dad401b52c8ff200caf41da",
                "categoryId": "5dc553ffd7b692257cebd170",
                "categoryName": "north indian",
                "subcategoryId": "5dc556ebcf881d19f4369f77",
                "subcategoryName": "subtest",
                "name": "Hand Fry",
                "price": 100,
                "dishImage": "/images/dish/1574405510680-1574405429836.jpg",
                "customizable": [],
                "addons": []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5df9da5bc20d011e7c394f36",
                "dishType": "veg",
                "recommended": true,
                "isCustomizable": true,
                "isAddons": true,
                "availability": true,
                "restaurantId": "5dad401b52c8ff200caf41da",
                "categoryId": "5dc553ffd7b692257cebd170",
                "categoryName": "north indian",
                "subcategoryId": "5dc556ebcf881d19f4369f77",
                "subcategoryName": "subtest",
                "name": "Rajdeep Special",
                "price": 130,
                "dishImage": "/images/dish/1576655451745-1576655324988.jpg",
                "customizable": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5df9da5bc20d011e7c394f38",
                        "price": 20,
                        "title": "250 GM"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5df9da5bc20d011e7c394f37",
                        "price": 35,
                        "title": "500 GM"
                    }
                ],
                "addons": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5df9da5bc20d011e7c394f3a",
                        "price": 10,
                        "title": "Ice"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5df9da5bc20d011e7c394f39",
                        "price": 30,
                        "title": "Tea"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5df725448b8247182080ec47",
                "dishType": "non_veg",
                "recommended": false,
                "isCustomizable": false,
                "isAddons": false,
                "availability": false,
                "restaurantId": "5dad401b52c8ff200caf41da",
                "categoryId": "5dc68d68ab42841948a56dd5",
                "categoryName": "chinese",
                "subcategoryId": "",
                "subcategoryName": "",
                "name": "This Is Or",
                "price": 20,
                "dishImage": "/images/dish/1576478019834-1576477996438.jpg",
                "customizable": [],
                "addons": []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5df7233dbac9d01b3022f846",
                "dishType": "veg",
                "recommended": true,
                "isCustomizable": false,
                "isAddons": false,
                "availability": true,
                "restaurantId": "5dad401b52c8ff200caf41da",
                "categoryId": "5dc8fa090535a7112c7b8cd4",
                "categoryName": "sweets",
                "subcategoryId": "5dcbd3268a276d0accc4cc75",
                "subcategoryName": "laddu",
                "name": "laddu n",
                "price": 30,
                "dishImage": "/images/dish/1576477501434-1576477479394.jpg",
                "customizable": [],
                "addons": []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5df777d6ac1fc41844eaa2e3",
                "dishType": "veg",
                "recommended": false,
                "isCustomizable": false,
                "isAddons": false,
                "availability": true,
                "restaurantId": "5dad401b52c8ff200caf41da",
                "categoryId": "5dc8fa090535a7112c7b8cd4",
                "categoryName": "sweets",
                "subcategoryId": "5dcbd3268a276d0accc4cc75",
                "subcategoryName": "laddu",
                "name": "laddu Wala ",
                "price": 30,
                "dishImage": "/images/dish/1576499158059-1576499116976.jpg",
                "customizable": [],
                "addons": []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5df721df466f951b044d588f",
                "dishType": "veg",
                "recommended": true,
                "isCustomizable": false,
                "isAddons": false,
                "availability": false,
                "restaurantId": "5dad401b52c8ff200caf41da",
                "categoryId": "5dc8fa090535a7112c7b8cd4",
                "categoryName": "sweets",
                "subcategoryId": "5dce9db6a1b36c03e019c22f",
                "subcategoryName": "milk cake",
                "name": "Milk ",
                "price": 30,
                "dishImage": "/images/dish/1576477151887-1576477133177.jpg",
                "customizable": [],
                "addons": []
            }
        ],
        "restaurentData": {
            "_id": "5dad401b52c8ff200caf41da",
            "name": "Trump Restaurant",
            "firmName": "Tramp",
            "email": "eggwalas@gmail.com",
            "phoneNo": "8282828282",
            "address": "Jaipur",
            "profile_pic": "/images/restaurant/profile/1572937985224-1572937977064.jpg",
            "lat": 26.852755861231476,
            "long": 75.80524798482656,
            "fssai": "1234567891"
        }
    }
}
```

code i did:

```
extension ResturantController : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categoryNameArr.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
        return categoryNameArr[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return allDishArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let data = self.allDishArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DishListCell", for: indexPath) as! DishListCell


        for i in 0..<categoryNameArr.count {
            let catName = categoryNameArr[i]
            print("categoryNameToFind :: ",catName)

            for j in 0..<allDishArray.count {
                let dishes = self.allDishArray[j] as! NSDictionary
                if let catNameFound = dishes.value(forKey: "categoryName") as? String{
                    //print("catNameFound :: ",catNameFound)

                    if catNameFound == catName {
                        print("Category Found")
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        if let dishType = data.value(forKey: "dishType") as? String{
            if dishType == "veg"{
                cell.imgVegNonVeg.image = UIImage(named: "veg")
            }else if dishType == "non_veg"{
                cell.imgVegNonVeg.image = UIImage(named: "non-veg")
            }else{
                cell.imgVegNonVeg.isHidden = true
            }
        }else{
            cell.imgVegNonVeg.isHidden = true
        }

        if let dishName = data.value(forKey: "name") as? String{
            cell.lblDishName.text = dishName
        }else{
            cell.lblDishName.text = "NO DATA"
        }

        if let price = data.value(forKey: "price") as? Int{
            cell.lblDishPrice.text = "₹ " + String (price)
        }else{
            cell.lblDishPrice.text = "NO DATA"
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Want to display data as appears in this screen shot attached

I tried:

1) Make a new array with all categories and the removed the duplicate entries from it, at last I have 3 array ["north indian","chinese","sweets"]

2) not how to stucked at how to show data in a cell specific to its header.

Tap this link for server response: [Server response](https://notepad.pw/fzsiqi20)

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Group the array with [`Dictionary(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init). It’s pretty easy.

Comment: Querry updated with code

Comment: You might want to use a custom UITableView Header and use a grouped TableView.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating TableView Sections from JSON Data Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427800/creating-tableview-sections-from-json-data-swift-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all parse your *JSON* with **`Codable`**. You can use the below models to parse your data.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let allDishes: [Dish]
    let restaurentData: Restaurant

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case success, allDishes, restaurentData
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let success = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .success)
        allDishes = try success.decode([Dish].self, forKey: .allDishes)
        restaurentData = try success.decode(Restaurant.self, forKey: .restaurentData)
    }
}

struct Dish: Decodable {
    let categoryName: String
    let price: Double
    let name: String
}

struct Restaurant: Decodable {
    let name: String
}
```

In the above models, I've only added some properties. You can add whatever properties you want to parse from the *JSON*.

Now, in your `ViewController` create a variable `allDishesArr` that will be used as the *dataSource* of your `tableView`.

```
var allDishesArr = [(String, [Dish])]()
```

Next, parse your *JSON* using above created models and save the response in `allDishesArr`. Use `Dictionary's` **`init(grouping:by:)`** to group the dishes based in `categoryName` and then modify the response using **`map(_:)`** like so,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    self.allDishesArr = Dictionary(grouping: response.allDishes) {  $0.categoryName }.map({ ($0.key, $0.value) })
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

At last, your `UITableViewDataSource` methods goes like,

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return allDishesArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allDishesArr[section].1.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DishListCell", for: indexPath) as! DishListCell
    let dish = allDishesArr[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblDishName.text = dish.name
    //add rest of the code
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let categoryName = allDishesArr[section].0
    return categoryName
}
```